# What is the Klingon translation of the word "character" in the sense of a written symbol?

Tags: star-trek, klingon-language

I have been searching for a suitable translation for this, but the best I have gotten is the word **ghItlh** which is a verb meaning "write, engrave, incise, mark (upon)." I am unsure if there is some prefix or suffix that can be affixed to the word to make it mean a marking, engraving, etc. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: [pIqaD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klingon_alphabets)

Comment: @Valorum the name of the alphabet is not equivalent to a character?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word [ngutlh] is listed by the [Klingon Language Institute](https://www.kli.org/about-klingon/new-klingon-words/n/) as meaning "letter, written character, glyph". This word was introduced at the 2016 Saarbrucken QepHom, a meeting of the KLI for which Marc Orkrand, the creator of the Klingon language, provides new words.

For upper and lower case letters, ngutlh tIn (literally "big letter") and ngutlh mach ("small letter") can be used respectively.

Comment: I had no idea there would be an exact translation. Thank you so much! I notice that this list is organized alphabetically by the Klingon translation. Is there some way to search through the English translations to find the Klingon words?

Comment: Theres an (unofficial?) app for both iPhone and Android called boQwi', which is regularly kept up to date with that list including any new additions and is searchable in both directions. It also contains grammar notes and other useful information. I heartily recommend it for any aspiring klingonist.

Comment: Thank you. I am currently working on a project that requires words that wouldn't be as common as most.

Comment: @TyHayes Qapla'

Comment: I'm the author of **boQwI'**. Just wanted to answer the "unofficial?" comment above. The app is not associated with CBS, Paramount, or the Klingon Language Institute.